# How to query active users in particular profile?

Tags: soql, query, profile, user

I need a count of active users in a particular profile. How can I query to get this count?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: select count(id) FROM user
 where profile.name='system Administrator' and user.IsActive=true

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use a **count** query:

```
Integer assignedUsers = [
    SELECT count() FROM User WHERE IsActive = true AND ProfileId = '<profile_id>'
];
```